# "sudo command" doesn't work, but "command" as root works

Tags: linux, passenger, root

I'm trying to install Phusion Passenger on Ubuntu 12.04.

When I try:

`sudo passenger-install-apache2-module`

...I get:

`sudo: passenger-install-apache2-module: command not found`

However, when I omit the sudo, it works fine. Also, when I log in as root and run `passenger-install-apache2-module`, it works fine as well. Why would `sudo passenger-install-apache2-module` not work when logged in as my non-root user, yet work fine when logged in as root?

Comment: Try as root: which `passenger-install-apache2-module` and post output here. Understanding what exactly the command is may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `passenger-install-apache2-module` is not on your path as a normal user, but it is as root. (it's probably in `/usr/sbin` - see below)

run `which passenger-install-apache2-module` as root and it will tell you where it is (which you can then run using `sudo /full/path/to/passenger-install-apache2-module`

`sbin` directories (`/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` normally) contain the commands that are used for system administration. Typically these require elevated privileges or just don't make sense for ordinary users to be running them. This is why by default these directories are not on ordinary user's paths - it would just clutter things up.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. It's located at `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module`. Still strange that the non-root user couldn't find it, considering I installed it with `gem install passenger` (no sudo). Perhaps my rvm isn't configured correctly (I did a multi-user install).